An impending autopsy on a totally paralyzed person who is still alive
I'm looking for an anthology of horror stories written in the 1970s that contained a story about a person (a man?) who was on a table and was scheduled for an impending autopsy. The person was fully aware of all their surroundings. They could hear everything that was taking place. The person did manage to twitch a finger but the doctors dismissed the movement and proceeded.
The book I read was a paperback. I think it had a black cover and may have had eyes on it. Of course, my brain might be remembering the original cover of Stephen Ling's Night Shift. The story sounds very similar to King's "Autopsy in Room Four" but I just reread that one, nor is it Michael Shea's as that one was from the doctor's perspective.
I have done exhaustive searches on Google. I even asked the oracle of all great horror/scifi/fantasy stories, Ellen Datlow. If you aren't familiar with her, she now works at Tor and was one of the editors in charge of acquiring stories for Omni magazine back in the day. She said it sounded familiar but could not identify the book.

Dang it... I was going to mention the Stephen King story...

That said, also, are there any fantasy or sci-fi aspects? Futuristic drug? Curse? Ghoul bite?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This doesn't sound like it has any fantasy or science fiction elements?  Stories must be on-topic to ask about here.

FWIW, if there are no SF&F aspects, there's always the Literature SE.

If one could confuse 1987 with the 1970s due to the vagaries of memory, "The Autopsy", by Michael Shea, adapted into the eponymous episode of Cabinet of Curiosities, would fit the question description.

FWIW, a summary of "The Autopsy" at https://matthewrettino.com/2022/09/20/weird-58-the-autopsy-by-michael-shea-1980/

Possibly's Louis Pollock's "Breakdown", which King's story was apparently based on. But I'm having trouble finding a description of the actual short story instead of the Hitchcock adaptation.

I have a vague memory of an audio version of someone reading a story like this.  Was the last line of the story something similar to "The last thing to go is the sense of pain" as the pathologist begins to cut into his skull?

Do note that there is a cover of Polyphemus, the anthology in which "The Autopsy" appeared, that is black with an eye, but it is much more recent. That said, there is an older cover with somewhat similar themes, albeit not as close a match. Obviously, the single eye is because Polyphemus was a cyclops, so it appears at least abstractly on all the covers.

Ah, and full version of "The Autopsy" at https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/books/michael-shea-the-autopsy/

"The Jigsaw Man" by Larry Niven has a scene like this.

"Breakdown" was found in "A Baker's Dozen of Suspense Stories", which has a black cover with a cupcake pan with Alfred Hitchcock's face on the tops of the cupcakes, which might match the memory. I found an online copy. He is saved by the end, by his tears.

I’m voting to close this question because there are no stated SF&F concepts. Maybe migrate to Literature SE?

It's also got a bit of "too broad" going in, particularly accepting that people often misremember time periods. There must be dozens of stories, minimum, involving autopsies of living people from 1960 to 1990 or so, and quite a lot of them probably were collected in anthologies with black on the cover (which the querent is not certain about in any case) or with eyes (which could be a person). We already have numerous possible matches in comments. And sure, some of them will not have any fantastical elements.

My thanks to everyone for trying.  I posted the question here as this stack had the most horror identification questions. I realize that the short story I am looking for does not have elements of science fiction like Michael Shea's or Larry Niven's stories. It is much closer to King's, but I am certain that was not it. I shall continue.

@MichaelG.O'Connell Would you like it migrated to Literature?

I didn't realize that was possible. That would be great. thanks again.
